# MySQL: Query Optimization

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT a.FundIDRecv,a.SubscribeDt, b.FundName, 
(
    SELECT SUM(c.PricePerWeek) 
    FROM tbl_Hive c
    WHERE c.FundID IN 
    (
        SELECT FundID from tbl_FundStatic 
        WHERE FundID IN
        (
            SELECT FundIDSend
            FROM tbl_FundSubscriptions 
            WHERE FundIDRecv = a.FundIDRecv
            AND SubscribeDt >= subdate(CURDATE(), INTERVAL weekday(CURDATE()) DAY)
        )
        AND UserID = '14'
    )
) as Price
FROM tbl_FundSubscriptions a, tbl_Hive b
WHERE a.FundIDRecv = b.FundID
AND a.SubscribeDt >= subdate(CURDATE(), INTERVAL weekday(CURDATE()) DAY)
AND a.FundIDRecv IN
(
    SELECT FundIDRecv
    FROM tbl_FundSubscriptions
    WHERE FundIDSend IN (
        SELECT FundID
        FROM tbl_FundStatic
        WHERE UserID = '14'
    )
)
GROUP BY FundIDRecv
```

This Query takes a huge amount of time to fetch data.

How can I optimize this query so as to make it execute and fetch results faster than it does?

Comment: Depends. What are your tables and indexes? That makes a big difference.

Comment: Tells out what the query shall do.

Comment: Please give DB structures (tables/indexes) and execution plan (explain) for your query

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace your nested selects by `JOIN` clauses. Take this for instance:

```
AND a.FundIDRecv IN
(
    SELECT FundIDRecv
    FROM tbl_FundSubscriptions
    WHERE FundIDSend IN (
        SELECT FundID
        FROM tbl_FundStatic
        WHERE UserID = '14'
    )
)
```

Why not just join `tbl_FundStatic` to the outer query like this

```
FROM tbl_FundSubscriptions a
JOIN tbl_FundStatic s ON (a.FundIDSend = s.FundID)
WHERE s.UserID = '14'
```

Of course, I don't know if this is still correct, but it'll give you an idea. Also, you should avoid nested selects in the `SELECT` clause itself. It's better to join `tbl_FundStatic` and then select fields from it

Comment: How can I do that? Can you provide more information on how to do that? I have no idea about it

Comment: Yeah i will try out that. Thanks for the input though.

Answer (score 3):

Untested but this will give you a go:

```
SELECT a.fundidrecv, 
       a.subscribedt, 
       b.fundname, 
       SUM(b.priceperweek) AS price 
FROM   tbl_fundsubscriptions a 
       JOIN tbl_hive b 
         ON a.fundidrecv = b.fundid 
       JOIN tbl_fundsubscriptions fs 
         ON fs.fundidrecv = a.fundidrecv 
       JOIN tbl_fundstatic fst 
         ON fst.fundid = fs.fundidsend 
            AND fst.userid = '14' 
WHERE  a.subscribedt >= SUBDATE(Curdate(), INTERVAL Weekday(Curdate()) DAY) 
GROUP  BY a.fundidrecv
```

You need to add indexes on the following columns:

- (a.fundidrecv,a.subscribedt)
- (b.fundid)
- (fs.fundidrecv)
- (fst.fundid,fst.userid)

Comment: I will check it soon and get back to you.

Comment: @Pentuim10 : Thanks for the input. I appreciate your effort but SUM(b.priceperweek) is showing wrong data. It does not show the expected result.

Comment: Update your original question, and describe what the query should do.